Discord.py bot going offline after a few minutes
So I have a discord.py bot I'm running locally on my MacOS and when I go afk or something like that the console prints out:
discord.gateway Shard ID None session has been invalidated.

But then when I go back on it says connected to session. How can I keep it online 24/7 without the session getting invalidated?
I have tried running it on VS code and terminal, putting loops in the code, but none worked.

Does this answer your question? When your computer is in sleep mode, can you make it so python runs?

If your pc goes to sleep it usually pauses the apps that are currently running, that means your token is probably expiring and discord.py cannot request a new one unless you "wake up" everything and the app starts running again.
One of the easiest ways to run a discord bot forever is to rent a VPS (small virtual server in a datacenter). It is pretty inexpensive for the basic configurations and will allow you to run whatever program you want without "going to sleep".
Even with a very basic VPS you can run a lot of simple bots at the same time on one server. It involves some experience with linux systems because you will have to setup some things through your terminal over SSH.

You don't exactly need a VPS. This is just an OS setting that can easily be fixed

I personally use OVH and netcup, but you could use a tool such as serverhunter.com to find exactly what suits your needs. As @BlueRobin mentioned, it is not absolutely necessary if you're just doing some testing, but if you plan on hosting your bot(s) long term it is definitely something I'd recommend
